# Changing YUM/DNF basearch on Raspberry Pi image?

Tags: fedora, yum, raspberry-pi, arm, dnf

I've followed the installation instructions for [Fedora on a Raspberry Pi 2](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi). I downloaded the MATE Desktop image [here](https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/23/Images/armhfp/Fedora-Mate-armhfp-23-10-sda.raw.xz) and verified it with its signature available [here](https://arm.fedoraproject.org/verify.html), and then copied it over onto my SD card.

I then setup a chroot environment using a static build of QEMU ARM, and was able to successfully `chroot` into the image. I can execute any ARM binary and connect to the network.

However, I cannot install any packages inside the `chroot` due to this strange error from `dnf`:

```
# dnf update
Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'fedora' from 'https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-23&arch=arm': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: file "repomd.xml" was not found in metalink
```

If I look at the metalink returned from that URL, there is only an `armhfp` repository.

As I'm assuming that this is a misconfiguration, is there a way for me to change the `basearch` variable defined by YUM to be `armhfp` rather than `arm`? Is there something else I need to do, something I'm missing?

`uname -m` reports the architecture:

```
# uname -m
armv7l
```

and `file` tells me about the compiled files:

```
# file /bin/bash
/bin/bash: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=04f0998ecd3bfaea23bab0223f7ce1f602296085, stripped
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of your  fedora repo? Please.

Answer (score 0):

This might seem overly obvious and simplistic, but it worked for me:

`sed -r -e 's/\$basearch/armhfp/g' -i /etc/yum.repos.d/*.conf`

This is a basic "search and replace" for all instances of $basearch and replacing it with armhfp.

Technically, it't not overwriting your variable as you'd asked, it's just removing the need to do so. HTH.